# Styling Radio Button When Selected Not Working

Tags: html, css

I am embedding some outdated and non-responsive 3rd party donation form code into our website and have been successful in styling some features, but stuck on styling the new radio button when it is selected. I have researched for hours and used known good code for this option, but it's not playing well with the 3rd party code.

Is there another way I can write the following to work with the 3rd party HTML?

```
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked  + label {
background-color: #bfb;
}
```

NOTE: The "<div class=" in the HTML I'm styling has multiple classes, and I'm only using a single class ".radio" to style the buttons. I have tried using multiple classes when styling, ie. ".field.radio" with no luck.

**3rd Party HTML Radio Buttons I'm Trying To Style**

```
'<div class="field radio 23552 required" >' + 
'<label for="23552"><input id="23552" name="donation-level" class="required" 
type="radio" value="25.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span 
class="label">$25.00</span></label>' + 
'</div>'
'<div class="field radio 23553 required" >' + 
'<label for="23553"><input id="23553" name="donation-level" class="required" 
type="radio" value="50.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span 
class="label">$50.00</span></label>' + 
'</div>' + 
'<div class="field radio 23554 required" >' + 
'<label for="23554"><input id="23554" name="donation-level" class="required" 
type="radio" value="100.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span 
class="label">$100.00</span></label>' + 
'</div>' + 
'<div class="field radio 23555 required" >' + 
'<label for="23555"><input id="23555" name="donation-level" class="required" 
type="radio" value="500.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span 
class="label">$500.00</span></label>' + 
'</div>' + 
'<div class="field radio 23556 required" >' + 
'<label for="23556"><input id="23556" name="donation-level" class="required" 
type="radio" value="1000.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span 
class="label">$1,000.00</span></label>' + 
'</div>' + 
'<div class="field radio other-option required" >' + 
'<label for="other-option"><input id="other-option" name="donation-level" 
class="required" type="radio" maxlength="255"></input><span 
class="label">Other</span></label>' + 
'</div>' + 
'<div class="field text other-amount" >' + 
'<input id="other-amount" name="other-amount" class="otherAmount" type="text" 
placeholder="$0.00"></input>' + 
'</div>' + 
'' + 
'</div>' +
```

**CSS**

```
<style>

.radio {
  margin: 10px;
  accent-color: blue;}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;}

.radio label {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0px solid #444;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;}

.radio label:hover {
  background-color: #8eeefc;
  color: #ffffff;}

.radio input[name="donation-level"]:focus + label {
  border: 2px dashed #444;}

.radio input[name="donation-level"]:checked  + label {
  background-color: #bfb;}

input[type='text'] { font-size: 14px; }
input[type='date'] { font-size: 14px; }
input[type='email'] { font-size: 14px; }
input[type='tel'] { font-size: 14px; }

input[type='number'] { font-size: 14px; }

input[type='zip-code'] { font-size: 14px; }

textarea[type='street-address'] { font-size: 14px; }

textarea[type='comment'] { font-size: 14px; }

select[type='state'] { font-size: 14px; }

select[type='country'] { font-size: 14px; }

select[type='province'] { font-size: 14px; }

select[type='frequency'] { font-size: 14px; }

</style>
```

New Donation Page URL: https://www.ip3action.org/donate-2

Answer (score 0):

Move your radio button tags so that they are not nested within the label. Format them so they look like the following:

```
<div class="field radio 23552 required" >
  <input id="23552" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" 
         value="25.000000" maxlength="255">
  <label for="23552"><span class="label">$25.00</span></label>
</div>
```

I think this is because the CSS selector ([Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)) you are trying to use is looking for the next label after your checked radio button within your div. However, there is not a label after your radio button (in the HTML the label starts before the radio button) so the CSS is not applied.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Both comments so far did the trick. I did edit in this format yesterday but must have had some errors. Thank you Gone Phishing!

Answer (score 0):

`+` Sign: is Adjacent **sibling** combinator. It combines two sequences of simple selectors having the same parent and the second one must come IMMEDIATELY **after** the first.
now your 3rd Party HTML Radio Buttons are child of your label element not sibling

```
//This will not work because it requests the label sibling that comes immediately after
//the input type radio, 
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked  + label {
background-color: #bfb;
}

//and the input element in your HTML structure is a child of the label element here
'<div class="field radio 23552 required" >' + 
'<label for="23552"><input id="23552" name="donation-level" class="required" 
type="radio" value="25.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span 
class="label">$25.00</span></label>' + 
'</div>'
```

You can either change the structure to something like this one or come up with another way to accomplish your goal.

```
//HTML
<div class="field radio 23552 required" >
<input id="23552" name="donation-level" class="required" 
type="radio" value="25.000000" maxlength="255"></input>
<label for="23552"><span class="label">$25.00</span></label> 
</div>

//CSS from your code
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked  + label {
  background-color: #bfb;
};
```

Comment: Thank you Razin! This and Gone Phishing's responses were a great help and I got the code modified just how we need it. Will post up with final results when done. Thanks again!